# How to write a DSL based on free monad?

Tags: haskell, free-monad

I'm playing with free monads in Haskell and I got stuck with defining the functions that lift the functor constructors in the Free monad.

I have the AppF functor as a sum of several functors, each representing an effect. One of these functors is DbTrF, representing db transactions effects.

So my AppF is defined like this:

```
data AppF a = 
  DbTr (DbTrF a)
  | ... functors for the other types of effects
  deriving (Functor)
```

my DbTrF is defined like this:

```
data Op i r =
  Get i
  | Insert i r
  | Delete i
  | Update i (r -> r)

data DbTrF a =
  UserTb (Op UserId UserData) (Maybe UserData -> a)
  | SessionTb (Op SessionId SessionData) (Maybe SessionData -> a)
  | ... here is the code for other tables
  deriving(Functor)
```

then I would like to have a **transact** function

```
transact :: Table i r t-> Op i r -> AppM (Maybe r)
```

...which I would like to use like this:

```
transactExample = transact UserTb (Get someUserId)
```

For that I want to introduce the type Table as the function which takes an operation and returns a DbTrF value:

```
newtype Table i r a = Table {tbId :: Op i r -> (Maybe r -> a) -> DbTrF a}
```

My attempt would be something like this:

```
transact (Table tb) op = liftF (DbTr (tb op ???))
```

but I'm not sure what to put instead of the question marks.

Is this a good direction to follow or am I doing it wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: I think it should be `transactExample = transact (Table UserTb) (Get someUserId)`

Comment: You are right. I didn't actually get to compile that part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's try to instantiate the body of the function progressively, keeping track of the expected type in the remaining hole:

```
transact :: Table i r a -> Op i r -> AppM (Maybe r)
transact (Table tb) op
  = ??? :: AppM (Maybe r)
  = liftF (??? :: AppF (Maybe r))
  = liftF (DbTr (??? :: DbTrF (Maybe r)))
  = liftF (DbTr (tb op (??? :: Maybe r -> Maybe r))
```

But we also have, from the type of `Table tb`, `tb :: Op i r -> (Maybe r -> a) -> DbTrF a`. Therefore `a ~ Maybe r`, and we can just solve the hole above using `id`, with a small change on the type of `transact`.

```
transact :: Table i r (Maybe r) -> Op i r -> AppM (Maybe r)
transact (Table tb) op = liftF (DbTr (tb op id))
```

Comment: I've tried that before, since all the examples that I've seen were using id, but it doesn't work. The error is  "Couldn't match type ‘t’ with ‘Maybe r’
      ‘t’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          transact :: forall i r t. Table i r t -> Op i r -> AppM (Maybe r)
        at src/App/AppMonad.hs:56:13
      Expected type: Maybe r -> t
        Actual type: t -> t
    • In the second argument of ‘tb’, namely ‘id’...
"

Comment: I changed the type of `transact`. There is no way otherwise.

Comment: I didn't see that. Indeed, with the type changed it compiles